# RangeValidator Can't Count?

Tags: .net, asp.net, validation, rangevalidator

I am trying to validate length of a string in a `TextBox`. Controls on page defined as follows:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TB" />
<asp:RangeValidator runat="server" ID="RV" 
MinimumValue="3" MaximumValue="20" 
ControlToValidate="TB" Type="String" />
```

But when page runs there is run time error occurred

> The MaximumValue 20 cannot be less
>   than the MinimumValue 3

Comment: `RangeValidator` is used to validate a range of numbers, not the range in the length of strings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You mention Type `incorrect`, it should be `Type="Integer"` instead `Type="String"`

Comment: Would changing the type to integer, help the user in validating the length of string?

Comment: Thanks Muhammad. I have had a similar problem. I have defined rangevalidator for integer values, but I haven't specified Type attribute. I noticed several times that if textbox in gridviewrow had have rangevalidator from 1 to 10, only 1 and 10 values were accepted by validator. I think that validator use string type if it is not specified.

Comment: This answer does not match the question.  Specifying `Type="Integer"` will not cause the `RangeValidator` to validate the length of the `Text` attribute.  It only causes the string to be parsed as an integer.

Answer (score 4):

Just use TextBox's MaxLength propery. That is used to Get/Set maximum number of characters allowed in the text box.

For minimum length you'll need to use a CustomValidator. In that call a js function which checks the length of the string.

Try this:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TB" />    
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="CustomValidator1" ControlToValidate="TB"
    Text="The text length should be between 3 and 20" 
    ClientValidationFunction="clientValidate" Display="Dynamic">
</asp:CustomValidator>


<script type="text/javascript">
function clientValidate(sender, args) {
    if (args.Value.length < 3 ||args.Value.length > 20) {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can not validate the length of a `TextBox` using a `RangeValidator` !! `RangeValidator` is used to validate the value of a field, not the length of this value.

To do that you can use other ways as `CustomValidator`.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax that worked for me correctly

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator34" runat="server" ControlToValidate="fname" 
            Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="email is required" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" 
            ValidationExpression="(\s|.){5,10}"> 
                  Length must between (5-10) characters</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```